# After adding new views in layout file , their id doesnt show up in DataBinding variable, it says cant resolve symbol

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am using databinding to bind views to an activity , It worked fine and I was able to access views through databinding object , Then I updated the layout file and added some more views , I build the project again but still now I am not able to get the new views that I have added , it says cant resolve symbol.

I tried building the project again it didnt work.

I tried cleaning the project and then building again it didnt work.

Here is the XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".DetailsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/backdrop_height"
            android:background="@color/textColorPrimaryLight">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/dimen_title_text_margin_start"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/movieBackdrop_iv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/image_placeholder_content_description"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/picture_placeholder" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/scrim" />
                </FrameLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/app_bar_detail_activity"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:contentInsetStart="@dimen/dimen_inset_start"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/arrow_back_white" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_placeholder_content_description"
            android:id="@+id/moviePoster_iv"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/small_poster_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/small_poster_height" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </ScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

[image: Here is the error]

Comment: Can you post your xml layout code and your log as well?

Comment: I have added the files

Comment: It wont compile there is no log only this `Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`

Answer (score 1):

Data binding fields will not be same as your id. IDs are given in **snake_case** and finally you will get your id field by **camelCase**

For example if you have set id `movieBackdrop_iv` then you can use `mBinding.movieBackdropIv`.

Use suggestions not just copy paste.

**Update**

I also have problems like you, just use clean, rebuild, or just run the project to get your newly added ids and variables in layout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , that doesnt work ,only the Id before edit works , not the id of newly added views , I will try to rebuild again, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Okay that for sure, if you add some new field and you don't get that in binding class, you have to rebuild project.